# Retrieve all repositories that contain a file in a path within a repository

Tags: github-api, octokit.net

I'm currently using [Octokit.Net](https://octokitnet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search/) in attempt to search and find repositories that meet a specific criteria:

- Repositories that include `Android` somewhere.
- Includes any `.xml` files within a path matching `res/layout`
- Has a minimum of 100 stars
- etc

**The goal is to find Android repositories over 100 stars that include any `.xml` files in the res/layout path.**

To do this, I've tried to create two separate requests, one in which I use a `SearchRepositoriesRequest` to find repositories that match the `Android` characteristics and stars.

```
var request = new SearchRepositoriesRequest("android")
                {
                    Stars = Range.GreaterThan(100),
                    In = new[] { InQualifier.Readme, InQualifier.Description, InQualifier.Name },
                    SortField = RepoSearchSort.Stars,
                };
```

I then add these repositories to a `RepositoryCollection` and use it within the `SearchCodeRequest` which my hope is that within each of these repositories I can then search for the `Extension`, `Language`, `Path`, and more.

```
var request1 = new SearchCodeRequest()
                {
                    Repos = repositoryCollection,
                    In = new[] { CodeInQualifier.File, CodeInQualifier.Path },
                    Language = Language.Xml,
                    Size = Range.GreaterThan(100),
                    Path = "res/layout",
                    Extension = "xml",
                };
```

**Generally speaking, is there a way to search a collection of repositories that includes a generic file in a path?**

I'm more or less seeing the same results from the [Advanced GitHub Search.](https://github.com/search/advanced) Sadly this makes me think this isn't possible today with GitHub v3 API.

I did find some limitations within various blogs and similar that seem like this might not be possible?

> **Considerations for code search**
>
> Due to the complexity of searching code, there are a few restrictions on how searches are performed:
>
> Only the default branch is considered. In most cases, this will be the master branch.
>
> Only files smaller than 384 KB are searchable.
>
> You must always include at least one search term when searching source code. For example, searching for language:go is not valid, while amazing language:go is.